# Difference between to forsake and to give up

Tags: phrase-usage

What is the difference between to forsake and to give up ?

I find the two following as right:

> He has been given up.
>
> He has been forsaken.

In which situation would you use one instead of the other.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this question asked and answered either here or on ELU in the past month or so, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Forsake* is quite literary, while *give up* is not. Also, *forsake* is a transitive verb, and *give up* can be both transitive and intransitive.

If you give up something, you stop doing **something** that you do regularly (e.g. to give up smoking/drinking alcohol/a job). We don't say "to give up somebody" because this phrasal verb is for activities, not people.

To forsake is to leave **someone**, or to stop helping or looking after them, when they still need you. So, the sentence "he has been forsaken" is correct. In other words, he has been left (by his friends, for example).

Comment: There is a famous song called *Don't give me up* that's confusing me.

Comment: @stbr are you sure it's not "Don't give up on me"?

Comment: Indeed you are right. So basically we can use give up for people if we add "on" between give and the pronoun ?

Comment: @stbr yes, though the meaning is a bit different. Read about give up on here - https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/give-up-on

Comment: Ok I see so if I got it right, when I say I give up on him I mean that I kind of lost hope and stop try but I don't forsake him aka I don't leave him alone (in poor conditions) ?

Comment: @stbr I think you're right.

Comment: Great thanks for the answer !

Comment: And there's another famous song used in the Film High Noon, ["Do not forsake me oh my darling"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4a_1UhwgFU)